# Rolling back to Apache 2.2 on debian

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apache-2.4, rollback

Is there a way to replace Apache 2.4 with Apache 2.2 on debian? All the "apache2" packages now install 2.4.

Comment: What version of Debian are you running?  And have you installed any third party repositories?

Comment: Why would you even want to? Besides a few minor configuration tweaks, 2.4 is a dramatic improvement over 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

As of http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apache&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all&sourceid=mozilla-search the Apache version in the repositories is 2.2 for all releases including Jessie.

Just >= Sid has 2.4.

If you find your system install 2.4 it means you're on Sid (or Experimental), so edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` replacing `sid` or `testing` with `wheezy` or `jessie`, and run `apt-get update`.

Comment: Worth noting that, at least as of this comment, the default on jessie is 2.4.